# Gulp browser-sync refreshing ATOM editor on file save?

Tags: gulp, atom-editor, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I have the following gulp file setup for testing purposes of small ideas etc..

My project is setup the following way

- Project

  - site

    - CSS
    - img
    - js
    - index.html
  - gulpfile.js
  - package.json

Every time a save a `html, css, or js` from the `site` directory, instead of my browser refreshing, my atom text editor refreshes. Its kind of annoying. I have other projects setup similarly  but they are work just fine. its just this one i can't seem to figure out.

is it my code, or something else?

```css
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  bs = require('browser-sync').create(),
  sequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src('site/css/*.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('site/css'))
    .pipe(bs.stream());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src(['site/js/*.js'])
    // .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('site/js'))
    .pipe(bs.stream());
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('site/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('site/'))
    .pipe(bs.stream());
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  bs.init({
    server: 'site'
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['site/css/*.css'], ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(['site/js/*.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch(['site/*.html'], ['html']);
});

gulp.task('build', function(done) {
  sequence(
    ['html', 'js', 'styles'],
    'browser-sync',
    done);
});


gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't have a body tag in my index file. Once I added it, atom stopped refreshing and browser-sync started working properly